# How do i load libraries in firebreath under windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, firebreath

I'm trying to use some functions from user32.dll in a firebreath plugin, and i can't for the life of me figure out how to link the library to my project.  I've tried adding
find_library(USER32_LIBRARY user32) and some variations like user32.dll user32.lib, adding the path to system32, etc.  It keeps saying USER32_LIBRARY is defined but set to NOT_FOUND.

I haven't found any good examples of how to link libraries from the system32 folder, anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your Microsoft Visual Studio should link user32.lib by default if you properly install it.

There is nothing to do with cmake find_library(). CMake is cross-platform makefile generator, while your question is Windows specific.

The better way to start - is [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm ok... how do i "properly install it"?  I want to use the RegisterHotKey method, and i've declared it as extern, but when i try to build it says it is declared but not defined.

Comment: The only idea comes to my mind - you using VS Express without SDK installed which should be downloaded and installed separately. Anyway it is better for you to clarify your question after reading documentation about DLL and remove cmake part from your question.

Answer (score 2):

As Sergey said, user32.lib will be there by default.

If there are any other libraries you need, you can add the library using the target_link_library command as described on the [Using Libraries](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Using+Libraries) page on firebreath.org

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} user32.lib)
```

Again, this isn't needed for user32.lib, but might be for other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually modify your project property to add the lib name and header file path. I have modified my project to add portaudio(a third party tool).